# iPhone 4 having trouble connecting with dock

Tags: iphone, speakers

My iPhone 4 has trouble connnecting to a Sony speaker dock, it will continuously charge.

Sometimes it will play music through the speakers; sometimes it will not.

If it is not playing music it acts exactly as it would if it were to play music (the play/skip area drops down over the volume) but nothing comes through the speakers.

If it DOES play music at all it often seems to come disconnected from the dock every 30 seconds or so only to reconnect itself and have to be pressed play again.

I believe that is just a problem with my iPhone 4's connecting area... any suggestions at all would be so helpful!

Comment: Sounds like the dock isn't working. You should try using another dock.

Comment: Tried another dock, same problem. Now it is even worse. Just charges but no other response. Tried a friend's iPhone 4 worked perfectly.

Comment: Take it to the apples store.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking inside your iPhone side of the connector?  I've noticed that a lot of pocket lint tends to build up in there over time and I just took a toothpick and dug all of it out.  My wife's iPhone wasn't syncing when connected to my laptop and this turned out to be the issue.